# Everything got wiped in Starbound

Tags: technical-issues, starbound

So I was just going to start up Starbound, wanting to check out the update that took it out of early access. I click on singleplayer, but NOTHING is there. Not one character. I look in the files and everything is still there but nothing in-game. How can I transfer it back? Did this happen to anyone else?

Comment: If the last time you've played was early during the beta, the game has had several updates that made previous saves incompatible.

Comment: I believe they wiped all saves when the 1.0 version was released. If I can find the link I'll post it.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill iirc they said around a year ago that that was the last time that they wiped saves.

Comment: When the game got to 1.0 it had a another save wipe.

Comment: @Riley They said that they had updated their save system so that character wipes were less likely to happen. They never said it wouldn't happen again.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was just wondering if it was normal.

Comment: yah this is like the 3rd time since they made the game public. wouldn't surprise me if there will be more.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the change to the 1.0 version included a wipe of older character and world save data.

Answer (score 0):

During Beta Phase and especially with the official 1.0 release, different characters and world wipe have been done. this is because of changes in world/character generation which made unusable the old data format.

So even if you still own those saves, they would be unusable.

If you start a new character, there should be no issue from 1.0 release. 
In theory they should not make wipes in the game anymore.
You can then use any sort of method (manual cloud syncing) to keep your game saves safe and even sync across computers